# ASP membership or facebook membership (working with db and process)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, facebook, membership

I want to ask you for something:

1. I want do an IS on asp.net (MVC) with my custom membership connected to MSSQL
2. On DB will be more things and there will be a lot of connection with "userId"
3. But it's not a necessary to create NEW account just for this IS (but you can)...
   But if you choose that you don't want create new account you can join with your FB.

But there is a problem... How create a design and working with my DB when you are just FB user and you want make some change (add some data to DB... And this data are connected to your account but it can be IS-account or FB, and of course I want to add users to roles, and with the FB? It's possible?)

Here is my part of DB which is responsible for memberships:

User:

- id ( uniqueidentifier PK)
- username (text)
- password..
- ....

Role:

- id ( uniqueidentifier PK)
- name ( text)

UsersInRoles:

- id ( uniqueidentifier)
- roleID (uniqueidentifier (FK from Role) )
- userID (uniqueidentifier (FK from User) )

And I am using an ID (PK from User table everywhere (in other tables) as signatures who add a new item and other)

Thank you.

Comment: What is an IS account?  What is an FB user?  Just want to be clear since Acronyms are ambiguous.

Comment: Ok, IS meaned Information system (web where you have your own members with accounts) and FB user is just guy who have account on FB pages :)